# How to fix this before_destroy callback [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I tried to write down a before_destroy callback, which should let users cancel a booking at least 2 hours before the departure time.

Here's what I wrote so far

**app/model/reservation**

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base 

  before_destroy :verify


  private
  def verify
     if !(:ensure_deletable)
       record.errors[:base] << 'error'
     end
   end

  def ensure_deletable
    if self.date_trip.to_time < Time.now + 2
      return true
    end 
   end 
end
```

This code gives me no error but it does let a user cancel a booking in any time..

Can you help me? thanks

EDIT:

thank to your answers I modified the code as here below.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_destroy :verify

  belongs_to :dep ,:class_name => 'Stop', :foreign_key => 'dep_id'
  belongs_to :arr ,:class_name => 'Stop',:foreign_key => 'arr_id'
  belongs_to :route
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :CountStop, :to => :route, prefix: true, :allow_nil => false
  delegate :city ,:to => :arr, :allow_nil => false
  delegate :city ,:to => :dep, :allow_nil => false



def verify
  if ensure_deletable
    false
  end
end    


private
def ensure_deletable
   if self.date_trip.to_time < Time.now + 2
     return true
   end
end


end
```

In this way I can cancel only the reservations that has at least two hours before the departure. 
Is this correct?

Comment: `Time.now + 2` adds 2 seconds. You can use `Time.now + 2.hours` instead or preferably `2.hours.from_now`.

Comment: you're right! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if !(:ensure_deletable)` doesn't invoke your `ensure_deletable` method. It checks if the *symbol* `:ensure_deletable` is `nil` or `false`. This will of course always return `false`.

To invoke your method, you have to write:

```
if !ensure_deletable
  # ...
end
```

or

```
unless ensure_deletable
  # ...
end
```

Furthermore, you probably have to return `false` from your callback as [noted by japed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32453563/477037).

Comment: Missed that, have edited my answer as a result.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you both, guys. I tried to edited the post with the final solution. Can that work?

Comment: *"Can that work?"* - you should test it yourself :-)

Answer (score 2):

Validation only occurs when saving or updating and object, it doesn't prevent them being deletable.  According to [APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/destroy) simply returning false from your `before_destroy` will stop the action from being done.

So try:

```
def verify
  if !ensure_deletable
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base 

  before_destroy :ensure_deletable

  private

  def ensure_deletable
    # can be deleted up to two hours before time
    deletable = Time.now + 2.hours < self.date_trip.to_time
    record.errors << 'Reservation can no longer be deleted' unless deletable 
    deletable
  end 

end
```